# Why does my order not get filled with MQL5?

Tags: mql5

Im trying to create a script with MQL5 which open and closes Positions.

I have created this test code:

```
#property copyright ""
#property link      ""
#property version   "1.00"
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Include                                                          |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#include <Expert\Expert.mqh>
#include <Trade\Trade.mqh>
#include <Trade\PositionInfo.mqh>
#include <Trade\OrderInfo.mqh>
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Inputs                                                           |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
input double PRICE=PRICE_CLOSE;
input double LOT=0.01;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Global object                                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
CExpert ExtExpert;
CTrade client;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Initialization function of the expert                            |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Create Variables                                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

string open_pos="false";
double sl, tp;

void OnInit()
{
 
}



void OnTick()
  {
   if((PRICE_CLOSE >= PRICE)&&(open_pos == "false"))
   {
      sl=(PRICE_CLOSE/100)*99.9;
      tp=(PRICE_CLOSE/100)*100.1;
      client.Buy(LOT,_Symbol);
      open_pos = "long";
   }
   
   if(open_pos == "long")
   {
      if(PRICE_CLOSE >= tp)
      {
         client.PositionClose(_Symbol);
         open_pos = "false";
      }
      if(PRICE_CLOSE <= sl)
      {
         client.PositionClose(_Symbol);
         open_pos = "false";
      }
   }
   if(open_pos == "short")
   {
      if(PRICE_CLOSE <= tp)
      {
         client.PositionClose(_Symbol);
         open_pos = "false";
      }
      if(PRICE_CLOSE >= sl)
      {
         client.PositionClose(_Symbol);
         open_pos = "false";
      }
   }

  }
```

It should open a position if the Price of the selected currency pair rises above the entered Price. However if I enter 1.182 and the price rises above 1.182 it doesn't open a positon as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a print(PRICE_CLOSE) you will view that the price is equal to 1.
A way to make it work is to use MqlRates for your EA.

MqlRates rates[] -- creates an array to access the current rates
You can learn more on this link https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/constants/structures/mqlrates

```
#property copyright ""
#property link      ""
#property version   "1.00"
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Include                                                          |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#include <Expert\Expert.mqh>
#include <Trade\Trade.mqh>
#include <Trade\PositionInfo.mqh>
#include <Trade\OrderInfo.mqh>
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Inputs                                                           |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
input double PRICE;
input double LOT=0.01;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Global object                                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
CExpert ExtExpert;
CTrade client;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Initialization function of the expert                            |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
MqlRates rates[];
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Create Variables                                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

string open_pos="false";
double sl, tp;

void OnInit()
{
 
}



void OnTick()
  {
  CopyMqlRates();
  Print(PRICE);
  Print(PRICE_CLOSE);
  Print(rates[0].close);
  
   if((rates[0].close >= PRICE)&&(open_pos == "false"))
   {
      sl=(PRICE_CLOSE/100)*99.9;
      tp=(PRICE_CLOSE/100)*100.1;
      client.Buy(LOT,_Symbol);
      open_pos = "long";
   }
   
   if(open_pos == "long")
   {
      if(PRICE_CLOSE >= tp)
      {
         client.PositionClose(_Symbol);
         open_pos = "false";
      }
      if(PRICE_CLOSE <= sl)
      {
         client.PositionClose(_Symbol);
         open_pos = "false";
      }
   }
   if(open_pos == "short")
   {
      if(PRICE_CLOSE <= tp)
      {
         client.PositionClose(_Symbol);
         open_pos = "false";
      }
      if(PRICE_CLOSE >= sl)
      {
         client.PositionClose(_Symbol);
         open_pos = "false";
      }
   }

  }


//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| FFUNCTION TO COPY MQLRATES FOR FURTHER USE                       |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

bool CopyMqlRates()
  {
//\\//\\ 

      // Time and price data
      
      int bars = 5; // COPY LAST 5 VALUES
      int copy = CopyRates(_Symbol,_Period,0,bars,rates);

  
  return(true);
//\\//\\ 
  }
```